# How can I access AsyncFileUpload class/object outside its events ,in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am working on an image upload module and have a `AsyncFileUpload` control in the page, which I believe (once user browse the file path) keeps the file in temp. buffer until you call the method `AsyncFileUpload.SaveAs(filePath)`,

the scenario in my case is that I want to call this method when use submit the complete form, (purpose is that if user have browsed the image and later on decides to cancel the operation then file must not be stored on server),

So instead I am trying to call `AsyncFileUpload.SaveAs(filePath)` inside `protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` but If i do so it give the NullReferenceException was unhand led by the user code.

I believe this is happening because `AsyncFileUpload` fires a postback event and hence when I am calling it again it empty.

Probably I need to store/access file form a temp buffer at run time.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

StackTrace shows :

at AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUpload.SaveAs(String fileName)
   at _default.btnUpload_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\Projects\ImageRepository_default.aspx.cs:line 27
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Comment: Post the stack trace of the exception

Comment: @DavidNelson thats perty lenghty to post here, I have posted below the  original question.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the control to `persist=true`, you should be able to access its contents outside of the AsyncFileUpload events.

Comment: In the current version of the control toolkit the property is called `PersistFile`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method, if you please, until you find a more elegant one.
First you define a static control:

```
private static AsyncFileUpload fu = new AsyncFileUpload();
```

then you add the following line in Page_Load:

```
fileUpload.UploadedComplete += fileUpload_UploadedComplete;
```

where

```
protected void fileUpload_UploadedComplete(object sender, AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
        {
            fu = fileUpload;
        }
```

where `fileUpload` is the ID of your `AsyncFileUpload` control used in your page/ Web User Control.

This will keep the details of the file selected for upload.

I use this scenario when the file exists already on the server and I have to promt user with a confirm alert (to agree to overwrite or not) (because this alert causes a postback so the info from ASU is lost)

Hope it can be of help to somebody, as I lost some precious hours searching for a workaround. Finally I came up with this, but I believe there is a more elegant way to do it.

Bye